# Possible to send bitcoins directly from Coinbase wallet to offline Armory wallet?

Tags: offline, bitcoin, coinbase-api, wallet

I accidentally sent bitcoins from my Coinbase wallet to my offline Armory wallet address. Is there a way to recover them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps  [bitcoin.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps Bitcoin would be a better place to ask

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of an offline wallet is to securely store your assets until you are ready to spend them. You can "recover" them if you still have the private key.

Back up your private key(s) right away, and then take your time learning how wallets work (both "hot" online and "cold" offline/paper). I recommend familiarizing yourself with offline wallets starting with the Bitcoin Armory video tutorials: https://www.bitcoinarmory.com/tutorials/armory-advanced-features/offline-wallets/offline-wallet/

If you have definitely lost your private key(s), then unfortunately the coins would be inaccessible forever.